# python django allauth terminal error

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am new to django so I followed books and I tried to implement django AllAuth after putting the right codes in the appropriate place I got an error when I tried to run the server. The whole project was working properly till I implemented the allauth into the project. Below is my Error from terminal and my settings.py

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/tryTen/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/tryTen/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 307, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/tryTen/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/tryTen/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/tryTen/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/tryTen/src/tryTen/settings.py", line 164
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /Users/Olar/Desktop/tryTen/src/tryTen/settings.py on line 164, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

**Settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for tryTen project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'ugbeadie@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'damilola007'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'tmujhqxuqkgm)3n%77f8g$@dxq*_((hxnwlg7b)ubwjbb9c&ep'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ctrybe',
    'contact',
    'crispy_forms',
    # The following apps are required:
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    # ... include the providers you want to enable:
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tryTen.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

)



WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tryTen.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static-only")
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static"),
)

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'   

SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = “username_email”
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET =False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL =LOGIN_URL
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL =None


ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS =3
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_HMAC =True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED =False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION =None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX =”My subject: ”
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL =”http”

ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET =False
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL =”/”
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS =None
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE =True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL =True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD =”email”
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD =”username”


ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH =3
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED =True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST =[]
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_INPUT_RENDER_VALUE =False
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 6
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION =True
```

I am running python 3.5 *** I have edited the question to include my settings.py *** Thanks in advance

Comment: for_user=1&is_active=1 this is not in my code

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: show your `settings.py`

Comment: edited and posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace **all** `“` on `"` example

old:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = “username_email”
#                              ^^^            ^^^
```

new

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
#                              ^^^            ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line 164 is

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = “username_email”
```

It seems you used different quotation markes here:

> “ ”

That might cause your error. Try to replace your quotation markes with

> ' '

or

> " "